# How to change the directory path stored in a variable using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make an application that has a GUI that pops up and you can move files from one folder to another, but I need to implement a way to change the directory of the source file and the targeted destination file. But I don't know how to approach this.

```py
import shutil
import os
import tkinter as tk

source_dir = '/Users/shane/Desktop/test1/'
target_dir = '/Users/shane/Desktop/test2/'

file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.testhi = tk.Button(self)
        self.testhi["text"] = "Move!"
        self.testhi["command"] = self.movefiles
        self.testhi.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                            command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")


    def movefiles(self):
        for file_name in file_names:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir) #for file_name in file_names:  #shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: [`tkinter.filedialog`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.filedialog) module has a number of built-in static factory functions, like `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()` you can use to do this.

Comment: How would I go upon implementing this? Do I create a button for the target and source directory?

Comment: If that is how you want your human interface to work. An alternative would be some sort of File menu or perhaps a Tool Bar across the top of down the side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I go upon implementing tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory() into this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64095357/how-could-i-go-upon-implementing-tkinter-filedialog-askdirectory-into-this)

Comment: Yeah, I think I made that post to provide a better explaination.