# How could I go upon implementing tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory() into this?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make it so in this simple gui, you can change the directory, for the source file and the destination file. From an earlier post, I saw I could use tkinter.filedialop.askdirectory, but I don't know how I should implement this into the code. Should I make a separate button for the source and target directory?

```py
import shutil
import os
import tkinter as tk

source_dir = '/Users/shane/Desktop/test1/'
target_dir = '/Users/shane/Desktop/test2/'

file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.testhi = tk.Button(self)
        self.testhi["text"] = "Move!"
        self.testhi["command"] = self.movefiles
        self.testhi.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                            command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")


    def movefiles(self):
        for file_name in file_names:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir) #for file_name in file_names:  #shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, it is better to show the current source and target directories to users using `Label` and buttons to change these directories using `filedialog.askdirectory()`.

Comment: How would I implement this though?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it.

Comment: @CommandBlock Do you still need an answer to this question? If you have solved it yourself, consider posting your answer for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this problem was to just implement, filedialog.askdirectory(), where it would replace the path I put for source and target directory.

Like this:

```py
import shutil
import os
import tkinter as tk

source_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
target_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()

file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.testhi = tk.Button(self)
        self.testhi["text"] = "Move!"
        self.testhi["command"] = self.movefiles
        self.testhi.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                            command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")


    def movefiles(self):
        for file_name in file_names:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir) #for file_name in file_names:  #shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You forgot to import `filedialog` module.  Better move `root = tk.Tk()` before the two `askdirectory()`, otherwise you will have two instances of `Tk()`, one created by `askdirectory()` implicitly and the `root`.